# How can we express the statement "$f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$" in predicate logic?

Tags: functions, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How can we express the statement

> $f$ is a bijection from $A$ to $B$

in predicate logic? Can it be expressed in first-order logic?

A problem seems to be that the sets $A$ and $B$ are different sets, while predicate logic applies to a single set. Is that correct?

Comment: Something like : "for any $x$ exists exactly one $y$ such that $A(x) \land B(y) \land F(x,y)$ ..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Establish Domain and Codomain:

$$\forall y~ \forall x~ F(x) = y \implies (x \in A \land y \in B)$$

Surjection:

$$\forall y \in B ~ \exists x ~F(x)=y$$

Injection:

$$\forall y ~ \forall x_1 ~ \forall x_2 ~ (F(x_1) = y \land F(x_2) = y) \implies (x_1 = x_2)$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $R(x,y)$ be the relation "$f(x)=y$", then we want,

To express that $f$ is defined everywhere in its domain:
$$\forall x( x\in A \implies\exists y R(x,y) \land y\in B)$$

To express that for a function $f$, each input can only have one output:
$$\forall x \forall y \forall z (x\in A \land y \in B \land z\in B \land R(x,y) \land R(x,z)\implies y=z)$$

To expression the one-to-oneness of $f$:
$$\forall x \forall y \forall z (x\in A \land y \in A \land z\in B \land R(x,z) \land R(y,z)\implies x=y)$$

To express that $f$ is onto:
$$\forall y( y\in B \implies\exists x R(x,y) \land x\in A)$$